Why does a perpendicular bisector of one line segment go through a given point on another line
PQ is a diameter of circle with center at O. Radius OC is perpendicular to PQ.T is another point on  circle O at which a tangent line is drawn.  The circle with radius CP and center at C intersects the tangent line at the point R. The line through R and Q intersects circle O at point S.Prove the perpendicular bisector of PR ( whose center is M) goes through S.enter image description here

This question will likely be closed unless you show your own work and where you have become stuck. A diagram is nice too.

I’m voting to close this question because stackexchange is not a "do my work for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.
